# how to select from database using an array in condition in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have an array called $slugs and I need to receive  data form database table called posts in single array how to archive that ?

Comment: Why not use `whereIn` `Post::whereIn('slug', $slugs)->get();`

Comment: Please add more informations and piece of code or pseudo code what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you have array of slugs like this `['slug', 'slug1', 'slug2']` and you want to get values from table where slugs matches your slugs array in a single query.

```
//Solution via eloquent
$slugs = ['slug', 'slug1', 'slug2'];

Post::whereIn('slug', $slugs)->get();

// Solution via Query builder
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$slugs = ['slug', 'slug1', 'slug2'];
DB::table('posts')->whereIn('slug', $slugs)->get();
```

If you want to convert all your posts response to an array and then assign it to `$slugs` array you should use below solution

```
$posts = Post::all()->toArray();
$slugs[] = $posts;
```

To know more about `whereIn` [visit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

Answer (score 0):

If am getting this right? You need to fetch your posts to an array called $slugs.
Simply:

```
$slugs = Posts::all()->toArray();
```